# ICollection Count method fails in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a ICollection of Projects in my user class

```
public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

When I try to render the count of projects in my view, it gives an error

```
<h2>You have @Model.Projects.Count() projects....</h2>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The error message would probably be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ICollection` doesn't have a `Count` method, it has a [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.count%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *property*. You are probably getting confused with the LINQ [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) extension method which is supported on an `IEnumerable` interface.

Just remove the parenthesis at the end of the `Count` call i.e.

```
<h2>You have @Model.Projects.Count projects...</h2>
```

Comment: Tried that but it's not working either. The error that I get is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what the issue was here. I added a constructor in my user class to handle the null reference exception

```
public User()
        {
            this.Roles = new List<Role>();
            this.Projects = new List<Project>();
        }
```

This did the trick.
And ofcourse I called count without the paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

In general, I've found it useful to write default constructors of every type, so that when stepping through a project like this I can visually see when each one is called.  Not having a copy constructor or something similar can mask odd issues like this and make debugging infinitely frustrating.